# How to set cookie for homepage only and not other pages using jquery.cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery("a.down-arrow-wrap").hasClass("fade-out-down-arrow")){
        jQuery.cookie('hide-down-arrow', true, { path: '/' });
    }
});

jQuery(function () {
    if (!jQuery.cookie('hide-down-arrow')) {
        jQuery("a.down-arrow-wrap").css({"display":"block"});
    }
});
```

In above code, I am setting cookie on page scroll. and on second part checking if that cookie does not exist than display `<a>` with class `hide-down-arrow`.

I want this to happen only on homepage and not on any other pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way, you can check the page name before display  or before check existing cookie,

try this:

```
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
var vars = query.split("/"); 
if ((vars[vars.length - 1]).toLowerCase() == "homepage.html")
   //if the cookie is exist then display <a>
```

Comment: how about `www.mysite.com` as my homepage.

Comment: @ Arya: With another one if,check the address bar if is equal yoursite.com then you are in home page, also you can define your code in homepage not all of them or your master page?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `path` option from jquery plugin to explicitly set cookie validity to particular page.

**[jquery-cookie path](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#path)**

> Define the path where the cookie is valid. By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where the cookie was created.

Comment: how to check for cookie, created on homepage ?